# Implementing MySQL tuner suggesstions

Tags: optimization, mysql-5.7

Mine is GoDaddy VPS with 4CPU, 8GB -200GB Centos server with WHM. I am using latest Moodle with MySQL version 5.7.29 on 64-bit architecture. I was advised to tune DB for better concurrent usage. I plan to allow around 120 or so users so that the server wont crash.
Upon running MySqlTuner, I got these suggestions:

```
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 21.8G (284.90% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.1G (498.59% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/700.2M
```

I dont know what should I do to address the above issues. The recommendations goes on as below:

```
*** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 700.2M) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

I have PhpMyadmin also SSH root access to the server..can somebody please guide me what variable and where I should adjust?

The output of ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31201
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31201
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The full MySqlTuner report is as follows:

```
[root@server ~]# ./mysqltuner.pl
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.29
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql.log(0B)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql.log is readable.
[!!] Log file /var/log/mysql.log is empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] /var/log/mysql.log doesn't contain any warning.
[OK] /var/log/mysql.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql.log
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql.log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 238.2K (Tables: 58)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 700.2M (Tables: 467)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 3d 0h 15m 47s (2M q [10.724 qps], 119K conn, TX: 2G, RX: 747M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 92% / 8%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 38.1G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 169.0M global + 257.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 21.8G (284.90% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.1G (498.59% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 56% (86/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.73%  (870/119906)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 2M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1K temp sorts / 344K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 10628
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 20% (85K on disk / 409K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (1K created / 119K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 4% (1K open / 47K opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(1400) is upper than number of tables(804)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (184/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (20K immediate / 20K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.4% (1M used / 8M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/233.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 98.3% (5K cached / 84 reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 27.8% (306 cached / 85 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/700.2M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.96% (614568104 hits/ 614827562 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 87.25% (1375128 hits/ 1576061 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 200933 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: https://bit.ly/2Fulv7r
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (10000) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (2000)
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 700.2M) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

Comment: If you would post the complete MySQLTuner report, we could provide more meaningful assistance.  There is valuable information we can not see with this part of the report. Also, from SSH login, please post from lx command prompt, results of ulimit -a  for list of OS resource limits.  Are you using HDD, SSD or NVME for data storage?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The storage is SSD and updated question with full report and the ulimit -a output.

Comment: Thank you for postings of 38 minutes ago. Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME (your 3 days will qualify)
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for that...here are the results: 
iostat-op: https://pastebin.com/RJt5dCpt, lcpu: https://pastebin.com/z5ZBYAW3, process list: https://pastebin.com/mALnED9r, status: https://pastebin.com/ss4RC0Ji, variable: https://pastebin.com/nNgvLh7Z. Thank you very much for helping me to this extent.

Comment: Your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES lists appear to be extensively edited.  Could you repost them as produced from MySQL?

Comment: when I type from terminal, the text goes out of window i am not able to capture all of them. so took all of them from phpmyadmin

Comment: Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and another method on our 'Data We Need' page to see if 'TEE' function suggestions will work for you to use email attachment for your data.

Comment: Yes, TEE function helped me! I have sent the output file...hope this will help

Comment: I ignore the "max memory usage" warnings from MySQL tuner; their calculations are flawed. Every MySQL instance I've ever analyzed has a theoretical "max memory usage" that is many times the size of physical RAM. The practical chance of using memory close to that level is close to zero. You simply aren't ever going to run `max_connections` threads at the same time, with all of them allocating the maximum size of every buffer possible. Instead of relying on MySQL tuner's theoretical estimates, you should monitor the resources your database server is *actually* using.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 9 to support your 86 max_used_connections (concurrent)
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 for higher IOPS with your SSD devices
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 402 for 6 days
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 1
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

For additional assistance view my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to improve performance.

Comment: From the Linux Command Prompt,

    ulimit -n 32000 and press Enter will enable more Open File handles.

For this to persist across OS restarts, consider the tips in this URL - https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/
 - but do not set your limit to 500,000 - 32000 should be fine for you at this time.  You may use ulimit -a at any time to confirm current Open File limit.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I will implement these changes and check how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have implemented your suggestions and here is the mysqltuner results:https://pastebin.com/uPQL4X8U Hope this will enhance performance

Comment: Thank you for the 2m37s MySQLTuner report.  Please run it again in about 3 days to compare with your earlier 3day 0hours report.  It will be interesting to compare the two reports for 3 days of activity.  Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: @doctshinds I noticed your newest MySQLTuner report indicates you have innodb_buffer_pool_instances count of 8.  With this number of instances, to conserve 90% of CPU cycles for the function, from MySQL Command Prompt, SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=100; and when convenient, add this to your my.cnf before the next stop/start or restart.

Comment: it is done and will send u the report by tomorrow...thank you :-)

Comment: I have just run the tuner and placed here: https://pastebin.com/uPQL4X8U

Comment: A MySQLTuner report is more useful after 24 hours of uptime that includes at least one typical workday.  The last posted report had less than 5 minutes of uptime. Maybe the middle of next week will include more helpful information.

Comment: ok sure. thanks. will do so and report